# Выравнивание блоков на Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Верстаю *header* сайта. Решил использовать flexbox.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: не удается выровнять логотип и меню в одну линию, и раcдвинуть их по разние края с помощью flexbox.

```css
header {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

header .logo {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

header nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: rem-calc(45px);
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .9;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Головна</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Афіша</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Репертуар</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Про театр</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Команда</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакти</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

[<sub>Пример на codepen</sub>](http://codepen.io/jSas/pen/qrPqXg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не тому блоку flexbox устанавливали.

```css
header {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header .logo {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

header nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: rem-calc(45px);
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .9;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Головна</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Афіша</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Репертуар</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Про театр</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Команда</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакти</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```